# html5 geolocation api: knowing when the user is being asked for permission and when the browser is trying to get the position

Tags: api, html, permissions, geolocation

I'm wondering if the html5 geolocation api allows a way (an event or method) to tell the difference when an user is being asked for permission to share his location and when (being the permission granted) the browser is trying to get such location.

What I want to do is:

1. Give the user the possibility to share his location with my site.
2. When the user's browser asks him for permission, show the user a little help with what to do on the browser's "asking bar".
3. If the user grants the permission, show a little loading sign with something like "... we are trying to get your location, hang on".

This is important because:

- It's always good to help out amateur users.
- At least in firefox (without googlegears), takes a lot of time to get the user's position.
- If the user saves his answer to that question in his preferences, there's no need to show again the help when trying to get the location.

This is what i'm doing right now is pretty straight forward:

```
showHelp();
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(permissionGranted, permissionDenied);
hideHelp();
```

But doing that i'm shoing the "help" everytime, even if the user has already granted the permissions. Also, it's a little bit awkward that, if the user was indeed asked for permission and then accepted, the "help sign" keeps showing till the browser gets the location.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 'hideHelp' in one or both of your callbacks.  see below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sample.showHelp();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sample.getPosSuccess, sample.getPosFail);
});

var sample = {
    getPosSuccess: function () {
        sample.hideHelp();
    },
    getPosFail: function () { alert('#fail'); },
    showHelp : function () { 
          // your code here
    },
    hideHelp : function () { 
         // your code here
    }

};
```